# Div Like search Using dat filter Property

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to implement search using data-filter property of div.
Here one issue with this.I want to implement a like search.Currently it is looking exact match.Where i need to make change to make it a like search

```
      <label for="search">Search Input:</label>
<input type="search" name="filter" id="search" value="" />
<div data-filter="vehicle1">vehicle1</div>
<div data-filter="vehicle2">vehicle2</div>
<div data-filter="vehicle3">vehicle3</div>
<div data-filter="vehicle4">vehicle4</div>
<div data-filter="vehicle5">vehicle5</div>


 $(document).ready(function() {


    $('#search').on('keyup', function() {
             var val = $.trim(this.value);

            if (val) {
               $('div[data-filter]').hide();
       $('div[data-filter=' + val + ']').show();

              }
 if(val.length == 0)
      {
    $('div[data-filter]').show();
      }
 });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look here: [CSS selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html), this is what jQuery's selectors are based on.

jQuery adds to that with the [Attribute Contains Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/)

Which in your case would work like this:

```
$('div[data-filter*="' + val + '"]').show();
```

Comment: it is not working.actually divs are dynamically generated like this.. var elm='<div class="fuelcont" data-filter="'+vehicleName+'" id="'+vehicleId+'">'+divcontent+'</div>';
                  $(elm).appendTo(container);..Among these dynamically generated divs, iw ant to filter

Comment: I think the fact that it wasn't working at first had not much to do with the provided answer, more with how you implemented it. So you can accept the answer..

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will work:

```
var $divs=$("div");
for(var i=0;i<$divs.length;i++){
  console.log("div's data-filter",$divs[i]["data-filter"]);
  console.log("value",val);
  if($divs[i]["data-filter"]
    &&($divs[i]["data-filter"].indexOf(val)!==-1)){
      $($divs[i]).show();
  }
}
```